# Mouse clicks do not register all the time Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mouse

I am using the `Input.GetMouseButton(0)` function and my program works fine except that not all the clicks get registered which is pretty annoying. Should I use something else instead of `Input.GetMouseButton(0)`?

Answer (score 4):

`GetMouseButton(0)` return true while the left mouse-button is held down. If you press and release the mouse-button too quickly, your Update might miss it, depending on your framerate. Use `GetMouseButtonDown(0)` instead (or `GetMouseButtonUp(0)`). This will return true in the next frame after the mouse-button has been pressed.